# How to draw a heatmap of similarity from two one dimensional arrays in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, heatmap

I have two arrays as following,

```
a = np.array([5., 10., 20., 19., 1., 10., 60.])
b = np.array([7., 10., 10., 17., 20., 0., 50.])
```

I want to be able to plot a heatmap showing how close array a, to array b. If possible, show the a value and b value on mouse hover. For example, 1 in array a, is not close to 20 in array b -- should be lighter color, etc. Any idea where to start? Thank you.

Comment: You could use [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)

Comment: Do you want a continuous map in 1 dimension? Or discrete coloured points along one axis?

Comment: @joostblack I wanted to draw a 2D plot. On x axis, a and y axis b -- something like this. Do you know how to get there?

Comment: Do you want the distance from one element in a to all other elements in b, and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit-learn has a handy [function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) to compute the pairwise distances. You just need to reshape the arrays, because it expects 2d arrays as input. Then I would also use seaborn, as Eduardo suggested.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import seaborn as sns

a = np.array([5., 10., 20., 19., 1., 10., 60.])
b = np.array([7., 10., 10., 17., 20., 0., 50.])

distances = pairwise_distances(X=a.reshape(-1, 1), Y=b.reshape(-1, 1))

sns.heatmap(distances, square=True, annot=True, cbar=False, cmap='Blues');
```

[image: heatmap]

**Edit:** To reverse the colors, you can use the colormap `'Blues_r'` instead. I don't know if there is a way to flip the y-axis at the seaborn level, but you can always flip the input data and change the labels accordingly:

```py
distances = pairwise_distances(X=np.flip(a).reshape(-1, 1), Y=b.reshape(-1, 1))
sns.heatmap(distances, square=True, annot=True, cbar=False, cmap='Blues_r', 
            yticklabels=list(reversed(range(len(a)))));
```

[image: heatmap, flipped version]

Comment: Thanks a million. Is it possible to flip the y-axis? And how can I set the color also in flipped-order? E.g., 10 and 10 should be darker as it is 100% same, 20 and 10 is 50% similar, and so on.

Comment: Sure, that's possible. I've added a paragraph to the answer.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Arne . Practically, my np array is large. I took only to 20. And it looks messy. a <-- array([207,  25,  63,  30,  36,  37,  43, 398,  27,  35, 246,  70,  33,
         6,  56,  28,  11,  10,  12, 320])
b <-- array([34, 24, 53, 33, 38, 41, 42, 48, 32, 28, 15, 49, 19, 12, 61, 30, 11,
       10, 33, 39])

Answer (score 1):

What does your data represent? There are many ways to compare things and determine whether they are different. You could compute the difference, the ratio, etc. There is not right way to address your question without a bit more context.

If your two values are supposed to be proportional, I would plot them as a scatter plot with each one as an axis

```
import pandas as pd
a = np.array([5., 10., 20., 19., 1., 10., 60.])
b = np.array([7., 10., 10., 17., 20., 0., 50.])
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})
df.plot.scatter(x='a', y='b')
```

[image: a vs b scatterplot]

You could also use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org)'s [regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.regplot(data=df, x='a', y='b', robust=True)
```

[image: a vs b regplot]

If you really want to use a heatmap, I would go for a [clustermap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) as this will cluster apart the values that are similar and those that are different:

```
sns.clustermap(df)
```

[image: clustermap]

Use the `annot=True` parameter to display the values:

[image: clustermap with annot]

Comment: Thanks a million. You have raised a good question. Array a is true-label, array b is prediction of a ML model. I wanted to show how the model performed. So, if you have other idea, please feel free to tell.